# Rearrange formula The Parallel-Plate Capacitor $C = (K\epsilon_0A/d)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need re arrange to find $\epsilon_0$ in the following formula $C = (K\epsilon_0A/d)$

Is is $\epsilon_0$ = KCd/A?

Comment: Multiplying both sides with $d$ yields $Cd=K\epsilon_{0}A$. Dividing both sides by KA gives $\frac{Cd}{KA}=\epsilon_{0}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that:
$$C=\frac{KA\epsilon_0}{d}\implies C=\frac{KA}{d}\cdot \epsilon_0$$
Now, you can multiply both sides by $\frac{d}{KA}$ to obtain:
$$C\cdot \frac{d}{KA}=\color{#CC0000}{\frac{d}{KA}\cdot \frac{KA}{d}}\cdot \epsilon_0$$
$$C\cdot \frac{d}{KA}=\color{#CC0000}{1}\cdot \epsilon_0$$
Therefore, your explicit solution for $\epsilon_0$ is:
$$\epsilon_0=\frac{Cd}{KA}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have that:

$$\text{C}=\frac{\text{K}\cdot\epsilon_0\cdot\text{A}}{\text{d}}\tag1$$

When we crossmultiply:

$$\frac{\text{C}}{1}=\frac{\text{K}\cdot\epsilon_0\cdot\text{A}}{\text{d}}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{C}\cdot\text{d}=1\cdot\text{K}\cdot\epsilon_0\cdot\text{A}\tag2$$

Now, divide both sides by $\text{K}\cdot\text{A}$:

$$\frac{\text{C}\cdot\text{d}}{\text{K}\cdot\text{A}}=\frac{1\cdot\text{K}\cdot\epsilon_0\cdot\text{A}}{\text{K}\cdot\text{A}}=1\cdot\epsilon_0=\epsilon_0\tag3$$